# Browser sound does not mute and comes from the ears speaker during calls

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, audio, calls, xiaomi

I have Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 Pro with Android 5.1.1 and MIUI 8.0.
When I have website with music opened and receive a call, I can hear the music from the ear speaker. It is wrong because I can't hear the other party properly.

Comment: What music app, this sounds like an app problem, or you didn't give it Phone permissions (so it can see call state).

Comment: @acejavelin It is not an app, it is a browser game: https://tr.fruitshake.mobi/